# Bootstrap background image in container doesnt work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a background image for my website, using bootstrap-4 and external css (internal doesn't work for me as well).

I am trying to add image which will be behind all rows which are in a

If i try to use it for a rows inside the container it works, but i wanna the background behind all rows, not just behind one.

Could you help me with that please?

```css
.background {
    background-image: url('images/podklad.png') !important;
    height: 100%;
}

#top_part {
    /*background-color: #ff9900  !important;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid background" >
  <div class="row" id='top_part'>
    <div class="col-6" >

      <div class="d-flex text-center justify-content-center align-items-baseline">
        <h1>bla bla<br/>bla bla</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><h4></h4></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/krabicka.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row" id='top_part'>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <h2>bla bla</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row" id='top_part'>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id='lock_gear_heart'>
        <img src="images/lock80px.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id='text_lock'>
        <h5>bla bla</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id='lock_gear_heart'>
        <img src="images/gears80px.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id='text_lock'>
        <h5>bla bla</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id='lock_gear_heart'>
        <img src="images/heart80px.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id='text_lock'>
        <h5>bla bla</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get an error in your console like a 404 for not finding the image?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code worked for me.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om8ghyst/) I created with example pictures. You can just replace my example images with yours. Your code correctly places the image behind the container with all of the rows.

If you want the image to be behind literally everything on the page, then change your CSS to look like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('images/podklad.png') !important;
    background-size: cover;  /* Resizes the image to cover the entire container */
}
```

If no image is showing up, then make sure the image paths are correct.